# Why I can not populate a listView and go back to main menu

Tags: android, android-studio

```
import static com.example.adimov.learneveryday.MainActivity.messagebox;  

public class NewMessage extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

Button save;
Button cancel;
EditText message;
String currentmessage;

ArrayList<String> ListFeeder = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newmessage);

    save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    message = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);

    message.requestFocus();                                                                         // Tezi dva reda mi vikat klaviaturata avtomatiqno kogato natisna butona za nova belejka
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){

    if(v == save){
        currentmessage = message.getText().toString().trim();
        ListFeeder.add(currentmessage);
        messagebox.setAdapter((ListAdapter) ListFeeder);
        goToMainMenu();
    }
}
public void goToMainMenu() {
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The last 7 lines of code is where both the problems happen, first I can not add the text from EditText to ListView and then it doesn't go back to the main menu, both of the problems are independent from one another, I checked that.

Comment: There are a couple things wrong with this. you need to assign a click listener to your save button. Also why are you using a list for one string? Wouldn't you be better off using a TextView? If you're statically importing a listview, you might want to pass the string back through to the main menu through an intent and then populate the list there.

Comment: I use a list because this is like a notepad, you can create a note and save it to the list and then add another note the same way and save it again and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.newmessage);

save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
message = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
 save.setOnClickListener(this);// add this
}   
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v){
 if(v.getId() == R.id.save){ //Here is another correction
    currentmessage = message.getText().toString().trim();
    ListFeeder.add(currentmessage);
    messagebox.setAdapter((ListAdapter) ListFeeder);
    goToMainMenu();
 }
}
```

Comment: what is the difference `(v.getId() == R.id.save)` and simply `(v == save)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like view.setOnClickListener(this) inside the `onCreate()`, you implements `OnClickListener` but you are not setting the listener on your view. 
Add this : `save.setOnClickListener(this);`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newmessage);

    save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    message = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);

save.setOnClickListener(this);// add this

    message.requestFocus();                                                                         // Tezi dva reda mi vikat klaviaturata avtomatiqno kogato natisna butona za nova belejka
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

}
```